# How to tell if a git operation is in progress?

Tags: git, version-control

If operation like `git pull` are run at the same time as a background build in watch mode (in my case, webpack), it can often fail because of the compilation locking files that `git` wants to overwrite.

I would like to add script to pause the watcher while any `git` operation is currently modifying the working directory. This should be possible because `git` itself checks if there is not another `git` doing something at the same time.

Note that I am not interested if a merge is in progress etc., I am interested if `git` is currently actively writing files.

Comment: Not an answer, but Git operations are supposed to be all atomic.  So one option might be to just keep trying to pull from your script until it succeeds.  There should be no risk of a partial corrupted pull.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to wrap your `git` commands (probably only the ones that change the index?) Otherwise `webpack` will have to continuously ping `index.lock` or something, and prevent you from making changes occasionally to prevent collision.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - does not work. If the `pull` is interrupted by an error that `git` cannot write a file, any other files that are already written, remain. Running a new `git pull` will error out because of existing changes in the working directory.
@kabanus - that would not work if some IDE is used for the git operations (that does not use git cli)

Comment: naive but effective: stop/run git/restart all in a script. May cost you some second each time, but I think still less than the time you will spend trying to make a more intelligent solution work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be enough to check if

```
yourepo/.git/index.lock
```

exists, when it doesn't create it, run a bit, delete it, sleep a bit, and then repeat. I think this is expensive if the background program really constantly runs. It may also block you at times from working until sleeping.

A feasible option would be to wrap the `git` commands themselves. Purely in bash a function would do:

```
function mygit {
    pid=$(ps -eo pid,comm a | grep webpack)
    pid=${pid%% *}
    kill -TSTP $pid
    git $*
    kill -CONT $pid
}
```

Running `mygit` will suspend your  process, run git, then let it continue. You can also change the way the `git` command itself behaves, if that's your preference, through the [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) mechanism, which you can fine tune to only affect stuff that only change the index, such as things to run pre (suspend) and post (resume) commit. A tutorial to initialize this can fe found in https://coderwall.com/p/jp7d5q/create-a-global-git-commit-hook - basically it's just scripts with specific names in a specified directory.

**EDIT**

After reviewing the comments below I want to add that the `git-hook` solution is completely feasible on Windows, since `git` comes with it's own bash on Windows. A tutorial on how to do this is https://tygertec.com/git-hooks-practical-uses-windows/ here, but make sure the scripts are all bash and anything above will work. The only caveat is finding and suspending the PID.

```
taskkill //PID <num>
```

will kill it, I'm not sure how to suspend though. Maybe on windows 10 with bash it the above will work.

Comment: the wrapper script assumes that git CLI is used and that it is not run on Windows. But thanks for the pointer to the lock file - that could be the answer

Comment: @Knaģis Correct sorry, perhaps add windows tag to question? And mention you use a graphical interface. The git hook would still work though, and is 'better' in a  sense. A `pre-commit` hook and `post-commit` hook splitting the above function may fix most of your errors (pull is just fetch and merge and commit, after all), but you may need to add a few more, or do a global one so it even affects status (for no reason).

Comment: @Knaģis I'm not sure how to find (automatically) and suspend the process though on Windows.

Comment: the index.lock seems better in my opinion - it should work without relying on OS specifics or modifying the repo (adding hooks) - which is better since the update would be distributed to 100 devs...

Comment: @Knaģis That still would be OS specific in terms of the script, in terms of checking if file exists and so forth. The main objection is that instead of `git` suspending only when needed the background process, your background process will have to continuously ping and sleep, making it quite a bit slower, if that matters. Also, I'm not sure how you're modifying `webpack`, but it will have to be somewhere in the process itself.

Comment: OS independent - in my case it would be a node script, but even in shell script file exists is simpler than manipulating processes. As for webpack - my plan is to add a plugin that will inject whenever the webpack wakes up because of file watchers and just wait until the lock file is gone. It might even write its own lock file so that git is then forced to wait until build completes

Comment: @Knaģis That's a good idea, if you get around to it you should post it and accept.

Comment: @Knaģis You can add another answer and mark it. It will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

By using `.git/index.lock` as suggested by other answer, I ended up modifying my build script to both wait for this file to be removed and to create it on its own during the build so that git cannot be started during build as well.

Posting in case the JavaScript code proves useful to someone else as well.

```
const gitIndexLock = path.join(__dirname, "..", ".git", "index.lock");
let hasWrittenOwnGitIndexLock = false;
function lockParallelGitOperations(callback) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(gitIndexLock) || hasWrittenOwnGitIndexLock) {
        writeLockFile();
        callback();
        return;
    }

    console.log("Git operation in progress... Waiting...");
    const sleepStarted = Date.now();
    sleep();

    function sleep() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (fs.existsSync(gitIndexLock)) {
                if (Date.now() - sleepStarted > 30000) {
                    console.log("Git has been locked for over 30 seconds. Removing foreign lock...");
                    fs.unlinkSync(gitIndexLock);
                } else {
                    sleep();
                    return;
                }
            }

            writeLockFile();
            callback();
        }, 200);
    }

    function writeLockFile() {
        if (!hasWrittenOwnGitIndexLock) {
            console.log("Creating .git/index.lock.");
            fs.writeFileSync(gitIndexLock, "");
            hasWrittenOwnGitIndexLock = true;
        }
    }
}
```